# From Silverlight OOB application how to check if a process is running

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, comautomationfactory

How can I query if a process is running on your Machine from a silverlight elevated trust enabled out-of-browser application?

Comment: Note that I already know how to do it using Shell.Wscript...I'm looking for better alternative way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (dynamic SWbemLocator = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"))
        {
            SWbemLocator.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3;
            SWbemLocator.Security_.AuthenticationLevel = 4;
            dynamic IService = SWbemLocator.ConnectServer(".", @"root\cimv2");
            dynamic QueryResults = IService.ExecQuery(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
            dynamic t = QueryResults.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
            {
                dynamic p = QueryResults.ItemIndex(i);
                MessageBox.Show(p.name );
            }
        } 
    }
```